# How to use ExtendedLog4netLogger.cs to set logfile path for appender at runtime?

Tags: log4net, castle-windsor, castle

I am trying to figure out how to use the [ExtendedLog4NetLogger.cs](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core-READONLY/blob/master/src/Castle.Services.Logging.log4netIntegration/ExtendedLog4netLogger.cs)
to change the log file path dynamically at runtime or using the LoggingFacility?

This should be something similar to using log4net directly like this:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = logName;
```

How would I access the ExtendedLogger if I register log4net integration like this:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net());
```

Update: I use the following code to register the Extended Logger

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(LoggerImplementation.ExtendedLog4net).WithConfig(configFile).ToLog(Lo‌gger));
```

I get no runtime exceptions and the logger is not a null instance but I don't see the log file created at all using the global properties, I also set the config value to  this for the appender:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
```

If I just set the file property in the config file to full path it does work. I am wondering if it is not working because configuration is done before setting the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extendedlogger.GlobalProperties["logName"] = logName;
```

To enable extended logger you need to do:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.ExtendedLog4net));
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, I updated my question because I am not sure how I would access this class using the registration of log4net integration that I use as shown in the Windsor docs.

Comment: This brings up other problems for me how to pass the config file path and use a named logger at the time of registration currently I do this: container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net(configPath).ToLog(namedLogger));

Comment: I will try this and see if it works: container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.ExtendedLog4net).WithConfig(configPath).ToLog(namedLogger));

Comment: Although I still don't understand how to do access the extendedLogger to do this: extendedlogger.GlobalProperties["logName"] = logName;

Comment: Yeah I am lost I am not sure how to resolve the extended logger to add the global properties.

Comment: I think I figured it out testing it now.

Comment: I see no runtime errors but for some reason I don't see the logfile created at the location I set with the globalproperties.

Comment: This is the line I use to register the Extended Logger: container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.ExtendedLog4net).WithConfig(configFile).ToLog(Logger));

Answer (score 1):

**1. How would I access the ExtendedLogger if I register log4net integration like this:**

Using the dependency injection you can expect IExtendedLogger object in the place where you need it.

**2. I am wondering if it is not working because configuration is done before setting the global variable.**

That's right. You need to reconfigure log4net after setting a property.

Here is an example:

```
using Castle.Core.Logging;
using log4net.Config;

class MyClass {
    private readonly IExtendedLogger _extendedLogger;

    public MyClass(IExtendedLogger extendedLogger) {
        _extendedLogger = extendedLogger;
    }

    public void MyFunction() {
        _extendedlogger.GlobalProperties["logName"] = logName;
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        _extendedlogger.Error("my error message");
    }
}
```